# Entering superuser mode with adb shell(on windows) on samsung galaxy s2

Tags: android, ubuntu, chroot

I tried to install chroot ubuntu on my phone but it was unsuccessful on my galaxy s2 (stock kernel, supports loop devices). The problem, I think, is that the adb shell is not granted superuser permissions (my phone is rooted and has superuser installed). When I type su in the adb shell, the superuser app on my phone doesn't notify me anything.

Comment: well im trying to install ubuntu on top of android using the following tutorial....http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using CM7 on my SGS Vibrant and `adb shell` defaults to having superuser privileges. You can tell if you have them or not by looking at the prompt; if the prompt is `#`, you have superuser privileges. If it's `$`, you don't. You don't need to worry about the Superuser app prompt if you have privileges.

Comment: well thnx...now im sure tat its not the error,however the problem is not yet solved...its giving an eroor when i enter bootubuntu...the image mite help...[IMG]http://i54.tinypic.com/122lnxv.png[/IMG]